# AJax call auto create html entities on wp_insert_user

Tags: wordpress

When I am trying create user using wordpress core function `wp_insert_user()`. It is printing:

```
<div id="acf-form-data" class="acf-hidden">
    <input type="hidden" id="_acf_screen" name="_acf_screen" value="post"/><input type="hidden" id="_acf_post_id" name="_acf_post_id" value="user_new"/><input type="hidden" id="_acf_validation" name="_acf_validation" value="1"/><input type="hidden" id="_acf_nonce" name="_acf_nonce" value="46e8a505a5"/><input type="hidden" id="_acf_changed" name="_acf_changed" value="0"/>   </div>
{"return":1,"message":"Successfully Logged-In!","uId":73694}
```

How can I remove this html code on my ajax request. I am returning  `echo json_encode($return, true);`  I want to only json data.

Answer (score 0):

Also had this problem could not find any solution online. The code ran just fine for a few years until a recent WordPress update.

Seems to be some kind of acf validation form echoing from within `wp_insert_user()` function.

Solved it with a kind of a hack by cleaning the buffer so it will not echo to the client, hope this helps as a temporary solution:

```
ob_start(); // Start the buffer
$user_id = wp_create_user($email, $password, $email); //Create user
$catch_echo = ob_get_contents(); //Catch the echoed content
ob_end_clean(); // Clean the echoed content
/// Continue code logic
```